# Dynamically Loading Collection View After initialization

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I created a collection view in obj-c and defined all the properties in view did load as following

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

    _collectionView=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:layout];

    [_collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [_collectionView setDelegate:self];

    [_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
    [_collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:_collectionView];
 }
```

So my requirement is: I want `[self.view addSubview:_collectionView]`, to get activated when I click some button, in the same view controller & as well as in different view controller.

Comment: Don't do [self.view addSubview:_collectionView]; in viewDidLoad. Do it on action event when button is clicked or any other view touchup and so on.

Comment: You can set the dataSource and reload in your button action and must have the same effect